# gnuplot: how to change the font of the label

Tags: fonts, label, gnuplot

In my script, I use 
`set label 1 "Stage 1 " at 15, 3.2 font "Times-Roman,18" front textcolor rgb "#FFFFFF"` 
to draw and control the label text. 
But I find the font does not work for me. Change the size of font, but the result is same, so what is the problem. 
Currently, I am using x11 terminal and gnuplot 4.2. 
My guess is some font is not supported. But I am not sure.

Comment: This font works fine for me. What is exactly the problem you're experiencing? Nothing shows up? Note you're choosing white as color for the text, so if the label is placed on a white area you won't be able to see anything. Also make sure `15,3.5` is within your plot ranges.

Comment: I place the label over rectangle bar. So the white color is just what I need. And the text shows up, but the size can not be controlled by the font. The text keep the same, no matter what font I use.